# Sorting VLC playlist using HTTP request based on their API

Tags: sorting, httprequest, vlc

When i tried to sort the VLC media from browser based on their API it just returns me an invalid search key error.

This is their API.

[image: VLC API]

The http request i used to sort the playlist is :

[image: HTTP request]

After i send the request VLC returns me this error:
[image]

This help would be a life saving

Comment: Good morning. Without any code it's impossible to help, at least for me

Comment: @TajinderSingh you can test it on your browser. but this question is mainly for those android developers that develops android remote control for VLC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider VLC media player `3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2` as the current version.

## HTTP interface: Sort playlist items

### Analysis

It seems that, currently, the following documentation sources are outdated:

- [VLC HTTP requests - VideoLAN Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HTTP_requests/).
- [vlc/README.txt at 3.0.17.4 · videolan/vlc](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/3.0.17.4/share/lua/http/requests/README.txt#L96-L105):

  ```
  > sort playlist using sort mode <val> and order <id>:
    ?command=pl_sort&id=<id>&val=<val>
    If id=0 then items will be sorted in normal order, if id=1 they will be
    sorted in reverse order
    A non exhaustive list of sort modes:
      0 Id
      1 Name
      3 Author
      5 Random
      7 Track number
  ```

It seems that the «Invalid search key» error is detected by the following piece of source code: [vlc/playlist.c at f32f289264fd4a08c8b5f04d8395ea78f358f291 · videolan/vlc](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/3.0.17.4/modules/lua/libs/playlist.c#L375-L377):

```
    /* allow setting the different sort keys */
    int i_mode = vlc_sort_key_from_string( luaL_checkstring( L, 1 ) );
    if( i_mode == -1 )
        return luaL_error( L, "Invalid search key." );
```

Please, note that the `vlc_sort_key_from_string()` function validates the provided `val` parameter value.

### Solution

The valid `val` parameter values may be found in the `vlc_sort_key_from_string()` function: [vlc/playlist.c at f32f289264fd4a08c8b5f04d8395ea78f358f291 · videolan/vlc](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/3.0.17.4/modules/lua/libs/playlist.c#L348-L362):

```
    static const struct
    {
        const char *psz_name;
        int i_key;
    } pp_keys[] =
        { { "id", SORT_ID },
          { "title", SORT_TITLE },
          { "title nodes first", SORT_TITLE_NODES_FIRST },
          { "artist", SORT_ARTIST },
          { "genre", SORT_GENRE },
          { "random", SORT_RANDOM },
          { "duration", SORT_DURATION },
          { "title numeric", SORT_TITLE_NUMERIC },
          { "album", SORT_ALBUM },
          { NULL, -1 } };
```

I have run a quick check: performed an HTTP GET request to sort items in a random order:

```
GET /requests/status.xml?command=pl_sort&id=0&val=random
```

It has worked correctly: the order of the playlist items has been changed appropriately.

## Autosave playlist upon application exit: Absent feature

This feature has been requested many times, but it has not been implemented yet:

- [Playlist autosave - The VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=61691).
- [Restore playlist state when re-opening app - The VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=155652).
- [Automatically saved/restored playlist (#4505) · Issues · VideoLAN / VLC · GitLab](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/4505).
- [Autosave Playlist (#4898) · Issues · VideoLAN / VLC · GitLab](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/4898).
- [playlist auto-save (#6010) · Issues · VideoLAN / VLC · GitLab](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/6010).

Please, note that it does not matter which type of user interface is used (for example, graphical user interface or HTTP interface).

### Workaround?

It might be a case that a workaround for your particular use case may be implemented.

For example, it seems to be possible to perform the following operations by using the HTTP interface:

1. To get the playlist and its items (`GET /requests/playlist.xml`).
2. To clear the playlist (`GET /requests/status.xml?command=pl_empty`).
3. To enqueue an item into the playlist (`GET /requests/status.xml?command=in_enqueue&input=<mrl>`).

Therefore, it looks like:

- The operation #1 may be used to implement the playlist items export functionality.
- The operations #2 and #2 may be used to implement the playlist items import functionality.

Please, consider asking a separate question with the detailed use case description.

Comment: Thank you Sir. But it shows that it sorts the item on the browser but when I returned back to VLC the items are not sorted.

Comment: Dear @gsharew, Good catch! Please, see the updated answer.